# Saber quando ouve mudanças em DIV com Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html5, dom

Olá, bom dia.

Eu preciso comparar uma mudança nas filhas da DIV1 para poder fazer uma notificação. 
Desta forma que fiz pode não ser a melhor, ainda estou aprendendo.

```css
<div class="div1">

           <div class="filha">
           <div class="filha">
           <div class="filha"> assim que adicionado o Js precisa ter como saber </div>
           <div class="filha"> se retirado tbm precisa saber </div>

</div>
```

```js
var myFunction4 = function() {
 jQuery(".div1").load(" meusite/minhaurl .div1");
};
var myFunction5 = function() {
 filhas = jQuery(".div1 .filha").length;
 //console.log(filhas);
};
setInterval(myFunction4, 10000); 
setInterval(myFunction5, 10000);
```

A função 4 pega os dados novos da "div1" e joga no local correto. 
Adicionando uma nova "filha" quando ela existe. (não sei se mexe no DOM)

A função 5 consegue saber exatamente o número de elementos filhos do pai(assim que adicionado ou retirado). 
Mas como saber anteriormente quantos eram ?

Pra poder comparar e assim poder notificar ? 
Esta é a forma correta ?

Existe uma melhor ? 
Abraços

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para saber uma mudança de algum componente você pode usar o MutationObserver. É bem simples seu uso:

```
let target = document.getElementById('div-pai');

let observer = new MutationObserver(mutation => {
    // Função vai ser chamada quando tiver inserção ou remoção de algum componente filho.
});

observer.observe(target, {childList: true});
```

Nesse exemplo eu coloquei para ele observar somente as mudanças dos nós filhos. Mas é possível fazer algumas outras observações, [referência](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: Então, eu tentei com observer. 
Mas sempre tenho este erro 
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Por isso desisti. 
Sou iniciante em JS. Não entendo pq não é um node 
Se dou um console.log no target recebo um Null

Comment: Funciona, o problema é que da mesma forma que o que fiz com Jquery 
Eu não consigo contar as novas mudanças :(

Answer (score 3):

Muito fácil, meu caro amigo. Ainda mais com JQuery!

Segue o passo a passo:

1. Pegue o html da primeira div
2. Pegue o html da segunda div
3. Compare as duas

Simples assim!!

Agora na prática seria:

```
htmlDiv1 = $("#Div1").html();
htmlDiv2 = $("#Div2").html();

if (htmlDiv1 != htmlDiv2) {
    // escreva aqui o que acontece quando as duas não são mais iguais.
}
```

Comment: Não entendi bem. 
O load coloca novas divs .filha 
Dentro de DIV1 

É preciso entender que serão várias filhas (ou não) dentro de DIV1 
Pelo que entendi não vai me avisar quando uma nova filha for adicionada via load()

Comment: Realmente, o código que está aí não vai avisar quando houver uma alteração. Mostrei apenas como fazer a verificação de maneira simples, mas ainda tem que colocar um setInterval() ou uma outra estrutura para detectar isso...

Comment: É exatamente isto que estou procurando. 
Como detectar

Comment: Ué, não entendi então. Você não tem controle sobre o que acontece no html? O que vai adicionar ou tirar as divs não é um script criado por você mesmo? Porque nesse caso é só você colocar nesse script que adiciona ou tira as divs o que você quer fazer, não precisa detectar quando acontece pois você sabe quando acontece. Porém se realmente você não tem controle então você pode tentar usar o MutationObserver.

Comment: Fiz via load por achar mais simples. 

Eu coloco via load() pegando via URL a mesma posição e jogando na mesma DIV.